# Mongoid embeds_many and has_many to the same model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I have a model "Person" that embeds_many "SuggestedPerson"s. SuggestedPerson also references another person (the person being suggested). So Person needs to both embed_many and has_many SuggestedPerson. The problem is Mongo is returning an error:

> Failure/Error: 
>        Mongoid::Errors::MixedRelations:
>
> ```
>    Problem:
>      Referencing a(n) SuggestedPerson document from the Person document via a relational association is not allowed since the
> ```
>
> SuggestedPerson is embedded.

Code:

```
class Person
  embeds_many :suggested_persons, :class_name => "SuggestedPerson", :inverse_of => :person
  has_many :suggested_to_persons, :class_name => "SuggestedPerson", :inverse_of => :to_person
end

class SuggestedPerson
  embedded_in :person, :class_name => "Person", :inverse_of => :suggested_persons 
  belongs_to :to_person, :class_name => "Person", :inverse_of => :suggested_to_persons
end
```

Is there a way around this?

Comment: The fastest way is to change association to has_many but this is hacky.

Comment: Yeah thanks, thats pretty much what I did :/

Comment: But I also want to know another solution not hack...

Comment: there isn't any other solution... an embedded document cannot be referenced by any other model than the model embedding it... cause as the [documentation](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/relations.html#embeds_one) says :`Documents that are embedded using the embeds_one macro are stored as a hash inside the parent in the parent's database collection.`
so they are not stored separately... therefore cannot be referenced.

Answer (score 0):

Since Mongoid can only do one or the other, a workaround is necessary. Here's an (untested) example that hopefully gets you going in the right direction.

If you need your embedded SuggestedPerson object to reference another Person object (besides the parent) you'll probably need to create a field on the SuggestedPerson embedded object, something like:

```
field :person_being_suggested_id, type: String
```

This attribute can store the ID of the other Person object. On your SuggestedPerson form, let's assume we've instance variable containing all your Persons in the SuggestedPerson controller (@persons = Person.all), and that Persons have a name attribute, that way we can just select from a drop down using this nice helper:

```
<%= f.collection_select(:person_being_suggested_id, @persons, :id, :name, {prompt: ""}) %>
```

In your SuggestedPerson model, you can have the following method:

```
def suggested_persons_name
  Person.find_by(id: self.person_being_suggested_id).name
end
```

That way, when you're working with an instance of the Person class, you can call things like:

```
@person.suggested_persons.each do |person|
  p person.suggested_persons_name
end
```

or say you're working with an instance of the SuggestedPerson class:

```
@suggested_person.suggested_persons_name
```

This first example will loop through all the embedded SuggestedPersons in a Person object, call the method suggested_persons_name on each and will return a list of all the names. The second example will only return the name of the person being suggested for that particular embedded document.